# Is there an event that is fired when a view exits?

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc-4

In asp.net mvc appliction, is there an event that is fired when a view exits? I want to save some screen settings when the view exits. 
This can happen when a user clicks on any other (page/view) link in the nav bar or logs off.[image]

Comment: you mean a event when the page refreshes

Comment: no only when some other view opens or application is logged off

Comment: what are those view that you are constantly talking about?aren't those pages?html pages?

Comment: yes for example about.cshtml or index.cshtml..so for example i want to leave Maps page and go to some other page at that point i want to save settings on maps page before leaving

Comment: i see so your views are pages, you need a unload event and some localstorage/sessionstorage/cookie

Comment: yes whenever the page unloads i need to do something

Comment: read https://developer.mozilla.org/ro/docs/Web/Events/unload    and https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/sessionStorage

Comment: or you simply use some get variables in your url

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So i am doing it on window.onbeforeunload event. Thanks to madalin and [this](https://www.codeproject.com/Questions/1046603/How-to-detect-the-page-unload-in-Asp-net-MVC) answer.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
 window.onbeforeunload = function (e) {

    var dataItems = [...];
    var model = JSON.stringify({ 'model': dataItems });

    $.ajax({
        url: "@Url.Action("SaveDefaultSettings", "Maps")",
        type: 'get',
        data: { defaultSettings: model },
    success: function (data) {


    }
});
};
</script>
```